# Expand 3D-Plot to canvas size

Tags: python, 3d, matplotlib

I would like to know how I can expand the 3D Plot to fit the canvas and if one can zoom in and out of the whole cube.
My goal is to make the Plot catch the mouse inside the whole frame, so you can turn the view. Only makeing the background white isn't enough for me. I want the Plot to file the canvas. Right now the axis tick labels can escape the plot frame. By expanding the plot this would no longer be the case, so I would also like to zoom out of the cube a bit. The standard zoom only changes the axis scale.
Look at the sample below to find out what I mean.

```
#! coding=utf-8
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def func(X,Y):
    return 1/np.pi/2*np.exp(-(X**2+Y**2)/2)

x = np.linspace(-5,5,200)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)

plt.figure()
sub = plt.subplot(111, projection='3d')
sub.plot_surface(X,Y,func(X,Y))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't understand your question at all.  is `tight_layout` what you are looking for?